# Gitlab Runner collapsed multi-line command for docker executor

Tags: docker, gitlab

I am getting this error for one of the `gitlab` `ci` jobs when the `gitlab-runner` is using `docker` executor and one of the images I built.

This is the job getting failed in `gitlab-ci.yml`

```yaml
image:
  name: 19950818/banu-terraform-ansible-cicd
.
.
.
create-ssh-key-pair:
  stage: create-ssh-key-pair
  script:
    - pwd
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh

    # below lines gives the error
    - |
      # !/bin/bash
      FILE=~/.ssh/id_rsa
      if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then
        echo "$FILE exists."
      else 

        ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa 2>/dev/null <<< y >/dev/null
      fi
```

But these lines **DON'T MAKE** the error when the executor is `shell`

This is the `Dockerfile` for the image `19950818/banu-terraform-ansible-cicd`

```
FROM centos:7

ENV VER "0.12.9"

RUN yum update -y && yum install wget -y && yum install unzip -y
RUN yum install epel-release -y && yum install ansible -y

RUN wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/${VER}/terraform_${VER}_linux_amd64.zip
RUN unzip terraform_${VER}_linux_amd64.zip
RUN mv terraform /usr/local/bin/  
RUN rm -rf terraform_${VER}_linux_amd64.zip
```

Can someone please tell me what is happening and how to overcome this problem?

My doubt is `ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa 2>/dev/null <<< y >/dev/null` line cause the error.

Comment: If anyone else makes it here looking on how to expand the *collapsed multi-line command*, I found an [answer here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/3392#note_368568570): use `set -xv`; while not perfect, it does help with showing more lines for debugging.

Answer (score 11):

Change `- |` to `- >`.

See also [GitLab Runner Issue #166](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/166).

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/166

Comment: Please edit your answer and provide relevant details how this code / link may help to resolve OP's issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
# below lines gives the error
- |
  # !/bin/bash
  FILE=~/.ssh/id_rsa
  if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then
    echo "$FILE exists."
  else 

    ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa 2>/dev/null <<< y >/dev/null
  fi
```

Despite the `# !/bin/bash`, that part of the command is most likely being parsed by `/bin/sh`. The various parts of the script are passed to the entrypoint of the container, which will be `/bin/sh -c`, and that will read the first line as a comment. If it was passed as a script to run, you'd at least need to remove the space, so `#!/bin/bash`, but I suspect it would still be read as a comment depending on host gitlab calls the script and merges with the other scripts to run.

Why would that break with `/bin/sh`? `<<< y` is a bash specific syntax. That could be changed to:

```
echo y | ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa 2>/dev/null >/dev/null
```

If you want to see error messages from the command to make debugging easier, then eliminate the output redirections

```
echo y | ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Or if you really want to use bash for other reasons, then change the entrypoint of the image:

```
image:
  name: 19950818/banu-terraform-ansible-cicd
  entrypoint: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
```